# Apply conditional to data being iterated over in list comprehension

Tags: python, list-comprehension, ordereddictionary

I have the following OrderedDict (I'm sorry for the formatting, I can't figure out how to get it to look readable). I basically have an object representing a conversation that sometimes has messages belonging to it and sometimes doesn't.

```
[OrderedDict([('id', 7), ('members', [OrderedDict([('id', 1), ('username', 'stefan'), ('email', 'sper1234@gmail.com')]), OrderedDict([('id', 10), ('username', 'Angela'), ('email', 'angela@testmail.com')])]), ('title', 'Conversation 1'), ('first_member_reveal', True), ('second_member_reveal', True), ('first_member_id', '1'), ('second_member_id', '10'), ('messages', [{'convo_id': 7, 'message': 'Conv 1 message 1', 'created_on': '03.05.2022 17:12:39', 'created_by': 1}])]), OrderedDict([('id', 23), ('members', [OrderedDict([('id', 1), ('username', 'stefan'), ('email', 'test@gmail.com')]), OrderedDict([('id', 11), ('username', 'Sharon'), ('email', 'sharon@testmail.com')])]), ('title', 'Conversation 8'), ('first_member_reveal', False), ('second_member_reveal', False), ('first_member_id', '1'), ('second_member_id', '11')])]
```

And I'm applying the following code to it in order to sort the dictionary based on the time at which the latest message belonging to each conversation was created.

```
sorted_data = sorted(
        serialized_convos.data,
        key=lambda x:
        max(datetime.datetime.strptime(msg['created_on'], '%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S') for msg in x['messages'],
        reverse=True)
```

The code does what I want but as mentioned, there is no 'messages' key in what I'm iterating over in some cases so I get a key error. I tried adding the following conditional in the list comprehension but it isn't working

```
max(datetime.datetime.strptime(msg['created_on'], '%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S') for msg in x['messages'] if 'messages'
    in x.keys())
```

I also tried adding an if/else conditional before the "for" part of the code and no dice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want the conversation without messages *move* to the back while latest messages are in front.

You can check if `"messages"` key is in dictionary and if not, supply some artificial old date. For example:

```py
sorted_data = sorted(
    data,  # <-- is your data from question
    key=lambda x: max(
        datetime.datetime.strptime(msg["created_on"], "%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S")
        for msg in x.get("messages")
    )
    if "messages" in x
    else datetime.datetime(1970, 1, 1),
    reverse=True,
)
```

Prints:

```py
[
    OrderedDict(
        [
            ("id", 7),
            (
                "members",
                [
                    OrderedDict(
                        [
                            ("id", 1),
                            ("username", "stefan"),
                            ("email", "sper1234@gmail.com"),
                        ]
                    ),
                    OrderedDict(
                        [
                            ("id", 10),
                            ("username", "Angela"),
                            ("email", "angela@testmail.com"),
                        ]
                    ),
                ],
            ),
            ("title", "Conversation 1"),
            ("first_member_reveal", True),
            ("second_member_reveal", True),
            ("first_member_id", "1"),
            ("second_member_id", "10"),
            (
                "messages",
                [
                    {
                        "convo_id": 7,
                        "message": "Conv 1 message 1",
                        "created_on": "03.05.2022 17:12:39",
                        "created_by": 1,
                    }
                ],
            ),
        ]
    ),
    OrderedDict(
        [
            ("id", 23),
            (
                "members",
                [
                    OrderedDict(
                        [
                            ("id", 1),
                            ("username", "stefan"),
                            ("email", "test@gmail.com"),
                        ]
                    ),
                    OrderedDict(
                        [
                            ("id", 11),
                            ("username", "Sharon"),
                            ("email", "sharon@testmail.com"),
                        ]
                    ),
                ],
            ),
            ("title", "Conversation 8"),
            ("first_member_reveal", False),
            ("second_member_reveal", False),
            ("first_member_id", "1"),
            ("second_member_id", "11"),
        ]
    ),
]
```